# Php file downloading instead of executing Blogger

Tags: php, blogger

Hi good day SO i would just like to ask why does the behavior of my code happens like this when I execute the page instead of executing the function of the php file.. I am also out of a clue if I still should include the  if I already have a php file? Thanks in advance I am just a newbie in web development please bear with me thanks again

```
 <form name='contact-form' action='mailto:dsadas@yahoo.com' method='POST'>
  <div>Name: </div>
     <input class='contact-form-name' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-name' name='name' size='30' type='text' value=''/>
     <div>Email:</div>
       <input class='contact-form-email' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-email'              name='email' size='30' type='text' value=''/>
           <input class='submit' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-submit' type='submit' value='Send'/>
        <div style='text-align: center; max-width: 450px; width: 100%'>
        <p class='contact-form-error-message' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-error-message'/>
        <p class='contact-form-success-message' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-success-message'/>
          <object width="400" height="300" type="text/html"   data="https://googledrive.com/host/0B-lp0v7FqyqRYzlmR3FfcDlGdGc"></object>
                </div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the blogger service to execute your php file?

Comment: What PHP file? also `action='mailto:dsadas@yahoo.com'` determines where the form is POSTed, so change it

Comment: @RobertMassaioli yes sir

Comment: @LozCherone If I already have a php file can I remove the form already? sorry for my ignorance I am a newbie :)

Comment: I think you should try and run your php elsewhere. Maybe buy web hosting. Blogger won't let you run code on their service; it would be a security risk.

Comment: @RobertMassaioli I have read somewhere that it is possible..But instead of executing the php file it downloads it. Can you suggest me some solution for this problem sir? Thanks Thanks

Comment: Wherever you read that, it's wrong. Blogger is not a web hosting service. It does not run PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer: You cannot host code on Blogger: anything that told you that is wrong. Go host it elsewhere.

You probably read a guide [like this](http://www.mybloggerlab.com/2013/10/how-to-easily-add-php-codes-in-blogger.html) (This does not deserve to be linked, it is full of wrong information but it serves the purpose of an example). This guide even says that you can host PHP scripts on Google Drive; I doubt that very much. If you want to host CSS and JS on Google Drive then that is a different story, because your users browser will download the code and run it.

To run a server side language like PHP you will still need to host the code yourself. [Try using Google App Engine to host your PHP apps](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/).